# Run function to all possible permutations in R

Tags: r

I have this in a text file:

```
Block    S1  S2  S3   M1  M2  M3  Label

Block-1  23  67  143  37  87  104 ""
Block-2  43  76  145  43  76  103 ""
Block-3  35  87  165  44  88  116 ""
Block-4  45  55  145  43  97  156 ""
Block-5  33  65  159  54  96  145 ""
Block-6  37  54  139  51  91  166 ""
Block-7  33  56  149  56  93  156 ""
Block-8  38  55  135  57  94  167 ""
Block-9  33  52  134  59  98  168 ""
```

So, I want to generate all possible combinations of 6 blocks from the 9 that are in the .txt file. Then, I want to apply the same function to each of the combinations generated to obtain the result for each of the combinations.

Specifically, I want to apply the "readAssayTable" function of the "pla" package, like this:

```
Data <- readAssayTable(paste(system.file(package = "pla"),
+                           "vignettes/CombiStat/data/"**all possible combinations"**,
+                              sep = "/"),
+                           rows = "Block", columns = "Dilutions & Samples")
plaModel <- plaCRD(Data); plaModel
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Take a look at `combn`. Without a reproducible example, it's difficult to say much more.

Comment: The subject says permutations but the body says combinations.